# call httpclient from servlet

Tags: java, servlets, httpwebrequest

pseudo code

```
service(..){


//httpclient get http://www.facebook.com


}
```

the above is pseudo code for java servlet, when user call this servlet service(..) from browser repeatly

for instance 

1. call  http://localhost:8080/callService?url=facebook.com/index.php

2. call  http://localhost:8080/callService?url=facebook.com/editprofile.php

can these subsequent request using the same "session" ?

Comment: Just a word of advice. You probably want to filter the url before passing it to the httpclient, otherwise some very bad people will do some very bad things with your server.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, writing a proxy server?

Comment: yes, trying. any hints wanna spare?

Comment: Why do you want to write one yourself? In my experience,anyone wanting to do this usually wanted to bypass corporate security in some way or another :).. Anyway, check out the various proxy servers already out there google.com/search?q=java+proxy+server

Answer (score 2):

Checkout [HttpState](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/apidocs/org/apache/commons/httpclient/HttpState.html) class to handle cookie and session. Here is the [sample code](http://www.theserverside.com/tt/articles/article.tss?l=HttpClient_FileUpload).

Comment: the example show sending cookie to remote server. can you elaborate more how to use this

Comment: There are two ways of maintaining session, cookies and url re-writing. The example mentioned, is showing the use of cookies. For a hint you can look for JSESSIONID, cookie name in the example.